# Placing a crossword puzzle into a tkiner in python 3.2

Tags: gridview, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.2, crossword

I managed to write code (through a tutorial) that runs for a simple crossword puzzle.  I'm pretty new at Python so I mistakenly used some code from 2.7 and some from 3.2  I think I managed to fix that, but now my goal is to make it "more pleasing to the eye".
At this point my words just appear on my Python Interpreter but I was hoping somebody could let me know what I would have to do on tkinter to get it to look like a proper crossword puzzle i.e. have the canvas draw a grid for my code so each word would appear in it's own little set of squares.  How would I go around that?  Below is the code I used for puzzle and the words (their lengths) that I'm trying to fit into the grid.
I was suggested to make an entry widget for each word but I have no clue how to do that. Thanks!

```
import random, re, time, string
from copy import copy as duplicate

class Crossword(object):
    def __init__(self, cols, rows, empty = '-', maxloops = 2000, available_words=[]):
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows
        self.empty = empty
        self.maxloops = maxloops
        self.available_words = available_words
        self.randomize_word_list()
        self.current_word_list = []
        self.debug = 0
        self.clear_grid()

    def clear_grid(self): # initialize grid and fill with empty character
        self.grid = []
        for i in range(self.rows):
            ea_row = []
            for j in range(self.cols):
                ea_row.append(self.empty)
            self.grid.append(ea_row)

    def randomize_word_list(self): # also resets words and sorts by length
        temp_list = []
        for word in self.available_words:
            if isinstance(word, Word):
                temp_list.append(Word(word.word, word.clue))
            else:
                temp_list.append(Word(word[0], word[1]))
        random.shuffle(temp_list) # randomize word list
        temp_list.sort(key=lambda i: len(i.word), reverse=True) # sort by length
        self.available_words = temp_list

    def compute_crossword(self, time_permitted = 1.00, spins=2):
        time_permitted = float(time_permitted)

        count = 0
        copy = Crossword(self.cols, self.rows, self.empty, self.maxloops, self.available_words)

        start_full = float(time.time())
        while (float(time.time()) - start_full) < time_permitted or count == 0: # only run for x seconds
            self.debug += 1
            copy.current_word_list = []
            copy.clear_grid()
            copy.randomize_word_list()
            x = 0
            while x < spins: # spins; 2 seems to be plenty
                for word in copy.available_words:
                    if word not in copy.current_word_list:
                        copy.fit_and_add(word)
                x += 1
            #print copy.solution()
            #print len(copy.current_word_list), len(self.current_word_list), self.debug
            # buffer the best crossword by comparing placed words
            if len(copy.current_word_list) > len(self.current_word_list):
                self.current_word_list = copy.current_word_list
                self.grid = copy.grid
            count += 1
        return

    def suggest_coord(self, word):
        count = 0
        coordlist = []
        glc = -1
        for given_letter in word.word: # cycle through letters in word
            glc += 1
            rowc = 0
            for row in self.grid: # cycle through rows
                rowc += 1
                colc = 0
                for cell in row: # cycle through  letters in rows
                    colc += 1
                    if given_letter == cell: # check match letter in word to letters in row
                        try: # suggest vertical placement 
                            if rowc - glc > 0: # make sure we're not suggesting a starting point off the grid
                                if ((rowc - glc) + word.length) <= self.rows: # make sure word doesn't go off of grid
                                    coordlist.append([colc, rowc - glc, 1, colc + (rowc - glc), 0])
                        except: pass
                        try: # suggest horizontal placement 
                            if colc - glc > 0: # make sure we're not suggesting a starting point off the grid
                                if ((colc - glc) + word.length) <= self.cols: # make sure word doesn't go off of grid
                                    coordlist.append([colc - glc, rowc, 0, rowc + (colc - glc), 0])
                        except: pass
        # example: coordlist[0] = [col, row, vertical, col + row, score]
        #print word.word
        #print coordlist
        new_coordlist = self.sort_coordlist(coordlist, word)
        #print new_coordlist
        return new_coordlist

    def sort_coordlist(self, coordlist, word): # give each coordinate a score, then sort
        new_coordlist = []
        for coord in coordlist:
            col, row, vertical = coord[0], coord[1], coord[2]
            coord[4] = self.check_fit_score(col, row, vertical, word) # checking scores
            if coord[4]: # 0 scores are filtered
                new_coordlist.append(coord)
        random.shuffle(new_coordlist) # randomize coord list; why not?
        new_coordlist.sort(key=lambda i: i[4], reverse=True) # put the best scores first
        return new_coordlist

    def fit_and_add(self, word): # doesn't really check fit except for the first word; otherwise just adds if score is good
        fit = False
        count = 0
        coordlist = self.suggest_coord(word)

        while not fit and count < self.maxloops:

            if len(self.current_word_list) == 0: # this is the first word: the seed
                # top left seed of longest word yields best results (maybe override)
                vertical, col, row = random.randrange(0, 2), 1, 1
                ''' 
                # optional center seed method, slower and less keyword placement
                if vertical:
                    col = int(round((self.cols + 1)/2, 0))
                    row = int(round((self.rows + 1)/2, 0)) - int(round((word.length + 1)/2, 0))
                else:
                    col = int(round((self.cols + 1)/2, 0)) - int(round((word.length + 1)/2, 0))
                    row = int(round((self.rows + 1)/2, 0))
                # completely random seed method
                col = random.randrange(1, self.cols + 1)
                row = random.randrange(1, self.rows + 1)
                '''

                if self.check_fit_score(col, row, vertical, word): 
                    fit = True
                    self.set_word(col, row, vertical, word, force=True)
            else: # a subsquent words have scores calculated
                try: 
                    col, row, vertical = coordlist[count][0], coordlist[count][1], coordlist[count][2]
                except IndexError: return # no more cordinates, stop trying to fit

                if coordlist[count][4]: # already filtered these out, but double check
                    fit = True 
                    self.set_word(col, row, vertical, word, force=True)

            count += 1
        return

    def check_fit_score(self, col, row, vertical, word):
        '''
        And return score (0 signifies no fit). 1 means a fit, 2+ means a cross.

        The more crosses the better.
        '''
        if col < 1 or row < 1:
            return 0

        count, score = 1, 1 # give score a standard value of 1, will override with 0 if collisions detected
        for letter in word.word:            
            try:
                active_cell = self.get_cell(col, row)
            except IndexError:
                return 0

            if active_cell == self.empty or active_cell == letter:
                pass
            else:
                return 0

            if active_cell == letter:
                score += 1

            if vertical:
                # check surroundings
                if active_cell != letter: # don't check surroundings if cross point
                    if not self.check_if_cell_clear(col+1, row): # check right cell
                        return 0

                    if not self.check_if_cell_clear(col-1, row): # check left cell
                        return 0

                if count == 1: # check top cell only on first letter
                    if not self.check_if_cell_clear(col, row-1):
                        return 0

                if count == len(word.word): # check bottom cell only on last letter
                    if not self.check_if_cell_clear(col, row+1): 
                        return 0
            else: # else horizontal
                # check surroundings
                if active_cell != letter: # don't check surroundings if cross point
                    if not self.check_if_cell_clear(col, row-1): # check top cell
                        return 0

                    if not self.check_if_cell_clear(col, row+1): # check bottom cell
                        return 0

                if count == 1: # check left cell only on first letter
                    if not self.check_if_cell_clear(col-1, row):
                        return 0

                if count == len(word.word): # check right cell only on last letter
                    if not self.check_if_cell_clear(col+1, row):
                        return 0


            if vertical: # progress to next letter and position
                row += 1
            else: # else horizontal
                col += 1

            count += 1

        return score

    def set_word(self, col, row, vertical, word, force=False): # also adds word to word list
        if force:
            word.col = col
            word.row = row
            word.vertical = vertical
            self.current_word_list.append(word)

            for letter in word.word:
                self.set_cell(col, row, letter)
                if vertical:
                    row += 1
                else:
                    col += 1
        return

    def set_cell(self, col, row, value):
        self.grid[row-1][col-1] = value

    def get_cell(self, col, row):
        return self.grid[row-1][col-1]

    def check_if_cell_clear(self, col, row):
        try:
            cell = self.get_cell(col, row)
            if cell == self.empty: 
                return True
        except IndexError:
            pass
        return False

    def solution(self): # return solution grid
        outStr = ""
        for r in range(self.rows):
            for c in self.grid[r]:
                outStr += '%s ' % c
            outStr += '\n'
        return outStr

    def word_find(self): # return solution grid
        outStr = ""
        for r in range(self.rows):
            for c in self.grid[r]:
                if c == self.empty:
                    outStr += '%s ' % string.ascii_lowercase[random.randint(0,len(string.ascii_lowercase)-1)]
                else:
                    outStr += '%s ' % c
            outStr += '\n'
        return outStr

    def order_number_words(self): # orders words and applies numbering system to them
        self.current_word_list.sort(key=lambda i: (i.col + i.row))
        count, icount = 1, 1
        for word in self.current_word_list:
            word.number = count
            if icount < len(self.current_word_list):
                if word.col == self.current_word_list[icount].col and word.row == self.current_word_list[icount].row:
                    pass
                else:
                    count += 1
            icount += 1

    def display(self, order=True): # return (and order/number wordlist) the grid minus the words adding the numbers
        outStr = ""
        if order:
            self.order_number_words()

        copy = self

        for word in self.current_word_list:
            copy.set_cell(word.col, word.row, word.number)

        for r in range(copy.rows):
            for c in copy.grid[r]:
                outStr += '%s ' % c
            outStr += '\n'

        outStr = re.sub(r'[a-z]', ' ', outStr)
        return outStr

    def word_bank(self): 
        outStr = ''
        temp_list = duplicate(self.current_word_list)
        random.shuffle(temp_list) # randomize word list
        for word in temp_list:
            outStr += '%s\n' % word.word
        return outStr

    def legend(self): # must order first
        outStr = ''
        for word in self.current_word_list:
            outStr += '%d. (%d,%d) %s: %s\n' % (word.number, word.col, word.row, word.down_across(), word.clue )
        return outStr

class Word(object):
    def __init__(self, word=None, clue=None):
        self.word = re.sub(r'\s', '', word.lower())
        self.clue = clue
        self.length = len(self.word)
      # the below are set when placed on board
        self.row = None
        self.col = None
        self.vertical = None
        self.number = None

    def down_across(self): # return down or across
        if self.vertical: 
            return 'down'
        else: 
            return 'across'

        def __repr__(self):
            return self.word

### end class, start execution

#start_full = float(time.time())

word_list = ['saffron', 'The dried, orange yellow plant used to as dye and as a cooking spice.'], \
['pumpernickel', 'Dark, sour bread made from coarse ground rye.'], \
['leaven', 'An agent, such as yeast, that cause batter or dough to rise..'], \
['coda', 'Musical conclusion of a movement or composition.'], \
['paladin', 'A heroic champion or paragon of chivalry.'], \
['syncopation', 'Shifting the emphasis of a beat to the normally weak beat.'], \
['albatross', 'A large bird of the ocean having a hooked beek and long, narrow wings.'], \
['harp', 'Musical instrument with 46 or more open strings played by plucking.'], \
['piston', 'A solid cylinder or disk that fits snugly in a larger cylinder and moves under pressure as in an engine.'], \
['caramel', 'A smooth chery candy made from suger, butter, cream or milk with flavoring.'], \
['coral', 'A rock-like deposit of organism skeletons that make up reefs.'], \
['dawn', 'The time of each morning at which daylight begins.'], \
['pitch', 'A resin derived from the sap of various pine trees.'], \
['fjord', 'A long, narrow, deep inlet of the sea between steep slopes.'], \
['lip', 'Either of two fleshy folds surrounding the mouth.'], \
['lime', 'The egg-shaped citrus fruit having a green coloring and acidic juice.'], \
['mist', 'A mass of fine water droplets in the air near or in contact with the ground.'], \
['plague', 'A widespread affliction or calamity.'], \
['yarn', 'A strand of twisted threads or a long elaborate narrative.'], \
['snicker', 'A snide, slightly stifled laugh.']

a = Crossword(13, 13, '-', 5000, word_list)
a.compute_crossword(2)
print (a.word_bank())
print (a.solution())
print (a.word_find())
print (a.display())
print (a.legend())
print (len(a.current_word_list), 'out of', len(word_list))
print (a.debug)
#end_full = float(time.time())
#print end_full - start_full
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution, without rewriting `Crossword` class:

```
... Your code ...

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showwarning, showinfo

class CellEntry(Entry):
    # My ugly entry-that-allow-only-one-symbol-strings
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        self._variable = StringVar()
        self._variable.trace("w", self._callback)
        super().__init__(master, textvariable=self._variable, **kw)

    def _callback(self, *args):
        value = self._variable.get()
        self._variable.set('' if not value else value[-1])

class App:
    def __init__(self, crossword):
        self.root = Tk()
        self._crossword = crossword
        self._grid = Frame(self.root)
        self._grid.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        # Cells
        self._cells = {}
        for col in range(1, crossword.cols + 1):
            for row in range(crossword.rows):
                c = crossword.get_cell(col, row)
                if c != '-':
                    entry = CellEntry(self._grid, width=2, justify=CENTER)
                    entry.grid(row=row, column=col)
                    self._cells[(col, row)] = entry
        # Numbers
        for w in crossword.current_word_list:
            row, col = w.row, w.col
            if w.down_across() == 'down':
                row -= 1
            else:
                col -= 1
            Label(self._grid, text=str(w.number)).grid(column=col, row=row)

        Button(self.root, text='Check', command=self.check).pack(pady=10)

    def check(self):
        for (col, row), entry in self._cells.items():
            if entry.get() != self._crossword.get_cell(col, row):
                showwarning('...', 'Something went wrong')
                return
        showinfo('...', 'Ok')

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

App(a).run()
```

Answer (score -1):

there is a problem whit your `App(a). run()` it says

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\alexr\Desktop\interface\interface tkinter.py", line 54, in <module>
>     App(a).run()
> NameError: name 'a' is not defined
> ```

you need to define it